# Express vector $\vec{w}$ in terms of dot product of vectors from basis $(\vec{v_k})$ of $n$ dimensional Euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

For given basis $(\vec{v_k})$ of Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^n$ find representation of vector $\vec{w}$ expressed by dot product $<\vec{v_k}, \vec{w}>$. In other words coefficients of $\vec{w}$ have to be expressed by dot product.

All I could think of is to use Gram-Schmidt process to form orthonormal basis expressed in terms of $\vec{v_k}$ and then easily just take dot products of $\vec{w}$ with each of these basis vectors. But this form is far from the expressions of $<\vec{v_k}, \vec{w}>$ and so on.

Is there another way which actually gives coefficients discribed by dot products mentioned before?

Comment: Is the basis arbitrary? If it is, then the expression is going to be rather complicated. You’ll basically have to expand $U^{-1}$, where $U$ is the matrix with the $v_k$ as its columns, by rows.